# How to insert a string between 2 consecutive ,?

Tags: text-processing

I want to insert a string possibly `N.A.` between two consecutive `,`.

This is my string.

```
5 Local A2A SMS valid for 1 day , 10 A2A SMS valid for 2 days , 10 Local A2A SMS for 2 days only , Daily 5 Local A2A night SMS for 2 days , daily 5 local A2A night SMS for 7 days ,,,,, 5 local A2A night SMS for 2 days ,,, Outgoing Rs 40/min and Incoming Rs 30/min. Applicable only on selected countries and Operators ,,, Outgoing Rs 30/min and Incoming Rs 20/min. Applicable only on selected countries and Operators ,,,,,,,,, 5 Local night A2A SMS(11PM to 6 AM-2 days) ,, 5 Night A2A SMS for 1 Day ,, Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min with Talk Time 25 in main A/c ,,, 5 night local A2A sms (2 Days) ,,, Top up TT in Main a/c 95.79 + 5 A2A Night SMS. SMS valid for 2 days ,,, 300 MB 3G/4G Data  , 138.51 TT(unltd val)+5 nite A2ASMS, SMS valid for 2 days , Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min with Talk Time 120 in main A/c ,, 500 MB 3G/4G data for 30 Days  , 2 SMS valid for 2 days , 1Gb 3G/4G and 100TT , 1.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 2GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 2.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 3GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 3.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 4GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 200 MB 3G/4G Data , Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min,
```

For example, there are 5 consecutive, 3 consecutive, 6 consecutive commas in the string. I want to insert `N.A.` between every comma.

`,,,,,` to be converted to `,N.A.,N.A,N.A.,N.A.,` etc.

Comment: If `$x` is your string with commas: `x="${x//,,/,NA,}"; x="${x//,,/,NA,}"; echo "$x"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo "your string with commas" | sed ':a;s/,,/,N.A.,/g;ta'
```

---

> `:a`: label with name a
>
> `s/,,/,N.A.,/g`: search and replace all (`g`) `,,` by `,N.A.,`
>
> `ta`: If `s///` has done a successful substitution, then branch to label `a`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in bash like this:

```
 a="5 Local A2A SMS valid for 1 day , 10 A2A SMS valid for 2 days , 10 Local A2A SMS for 2 days only , Daily 5 Local A2A night SMS for 2 days , daily 5 local A2A night SMS for 7 days ,,,,, 5 local A2A night SMS for 2 days ,,, Outgoing Rs 40/min and Incoming Rs 30/min. Applicable only on selected countries and Operators ,,, Outgoing Rs 30/min and Incoming Rs 20/min. Applicable only on selected countries and Operators ,,,,,,,,, 5 Local night A2A SMS(11PM to 6 AM-2 days) ,, 5 Night A2A SMS for 1 Day ,, Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min with Talk Time 25 in main A/c ,,, 5 night local A2A sms (2 Days) ,,, Top up TT in Main a/c 95.79 + 5 A2A Night SMS. SMS valid for 2 days ,,, 300 MB 3G/4G Data  , 138.51 TT(unltd val)+5 nite A2ASMS, SMS valid for 2 days , Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min, STD @1.15Rs/min with Talk Time 120 in main A/c ,, 500 MB 3G/4G data for 30 Days  , 2 SMS valid for 2 days , 1Gb 3G/4G and 100TT , 1.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 2GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 2.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 3GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 3.5GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 4GB 3G/4G and 100TT , 200 MB 3G/4G Data , Roaming Tariff - Incoming Free, Outgoing local @ 80p/min,"
 b=
 while [ "$b" != "$a" ]
 do 
   b="$a"
   a="${a/,,/,N.A.,}"
 done
 echo "$a"
```